# Which should be chosen amongst Node.js, Java NIO and Go(Golang)?

Tags: node.js, go, server-side, nio

Basically its server side scripting and per minute polling is required. Should be fast and comparatively easy to develop. Also some advantages/disadvantages of the three.

Comment: Questions asking the community to pick a technology aren't a good match for StackOverflow. Pick what works well for your skills and the project requirements.

Comment: Basically as WiredPrairie said. If _ease to develop_ is a factor I'd say raw java nio is probably not a good fit, but whatever floats your boat. Pick based on your / your teams existing skills. None of these are really a bad choice.

Comment: Thanks @Cubic- The priority isn't "easy to develop", just wanted to know the advantages/disadvantages of the three.